# Using a dash in a xpath does not work in py-dom-xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm curreny using [py-dom-xpath](http://code.google.com/p/py-dom-xpath/downloads/list) with python 2.7.2 under Debian 4.1.1-21.
Everything works pretty well, instead of one XML element.

Whenever I try to check a XML document for a xpath like `//AAA/BBB/CCC-DDD` the path is not found. It's the only node with a dash `-` in it. I already tried to escape the dash, but that didn't work.

I also tried `//*[name()='CCC-DDD']` and the `starts-with` and `contains` statement. The element is definately in the XML and the spelling is also correct.

I tried an [online xpath validation site](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm), and it works flawless there, even with the dash.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you try lxml.etree ?? It's an efficient and pythonic way of parsing xml.

Comment: With the sample XML from @unutbu, `'''<root><AAA><BBB><CCC-DDD>xyz</CCC-DDD></BBB></AAA></root>'''`, Python 2.7.3 on Debian Wheezy, and py-dom-xpath-0.1, `xpath.findnode('//AAA/BBB/CCC-DDD', doc)` works for me. Can you provide your XML input document?

Comment: Apert from your question: Debian 4? Is hasn't gotten security fixes in 4 years... you should seriously consider updating.

Comment: Also, if this doesn't work it could be a bug within py-dom-xpath (because it is valid XML). It could be also some kind of encoding issue. Could you provide a small example data set (SSCCE)?

Answer (score 1):

Is using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) an option? Dashes in the XPath work fine there:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content = '''<root><AAA><BBB><CCC-DDD>xyz</CCC-DDD></BBB></AAA></root>'''
doc = ET.fromstring(content)
print(doc.xpath('//AAA/BBB/CCC-DDD'))
```

yields

```
[<Element CCC-DDD at 0xb746f504>]
```

Answer (score 1):

> It could be also some kind of encoding issue.

This is a very possible cause of problems here. Confirm that the dashes are actually U+002D ('`-`') by grepping to show the context around every dash in the file:

```
grep -o '...-...' input-file.xml
```

And also in your script. [Different characters that look like dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Common_dashes) [(etc.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Similar_Unicode_characters) won't match each other.